# Get multiple average values in raw expression - Laravel MongoDB jenssegers

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using Laravel with MongoDB and [jenssegers package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operations). I have a collection called ProductDetails in which I have three fields for which I need to retrieve the average value: price, margin and weight. I can make three different queries but I would like to get that in one query. I think it would be cleaner.
I tried using raw expressions but I cannot make it work. I can't even retrieve the average of a single value. I have seen many people using mongoDB aggregation but I don't see why and how it would be useful here.

Here's what I'd love to achieve:

```
$productDetails = ProductDetails::select('AVG(price) as avg_price','AVG(margin) as avg_margin','AVG(weight) as avg_weight')
  ->where('id', '=', $id)
  ->where('active', '=', true)
  ->get();
```

It works when I try to retrieve the values (not the average) but the select does not work with `AVG()` which is why I wanted to use raw expressions

This is an unfruitful attempt:

```
  $productDetails = ProductDetails::raw(function($collection)
  {
    return $collection ->find([
      'name' => 'First product',
      'avg_price' => ['$avg' => "price"]
    ]);

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw) :

```
$productDetails = ProductDetails::selectRaw('AVG(price) as avg_price, AVG(margin) as avg_margin, AVG(weight) as avg_weight')
  ->where('id', '=', $id)
  ->where('active', '=', true)
  ->get();
```

be careful about the ' location, it should be around the hole statement in select raw expressions.

but :

```
 ->where('id', '=', $id)
```

this statment will make the query return only one row, I think you mean

```
 ->where('product_id', '=', $id)
```

is not?

Comment: I get an `Illegal offset type` error on the `get()`. Even if I only keep the `selectRaw` and the `get` and remove the where conditions. It should indeed be product_id !

Comment: mmm, I have tested the code I sent to you about selectRaw, other things I will let the decision to you